# sql query to get the data with respect to max and min dates group by

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we achieve to get the data based on the max/min processed dates and get the corresponding values
from the example below

[image]

and the desired output is
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle supports the `keep` syntax for this purse:

```
select id,
       min(qty) keep (dense_rank first order by processed_dt asc) as qty_first_date,
       min(qty) keep (dense_rank first order by processed_dt desc) as qty_last_date
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: The "`keep` syntax" is technically known as the "`first / last` aggregate function" (and/or the analytic function counterparts, which also exist). This is particularly relevant when one needs to search the documentation - it helps to know what Oracle calls this "thing" officially.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Emp_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(start_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_id ORDER BY Processed_at) min_date_start_qty,
       FIRST_VALUE(end_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_id ORDER BY Processed_at DESC) max_date_end_qty 
FROM tablename
```